# tuleap docker image redirect on localhost

Tags: localhost, docker, tuleap

I Tried to install Tuleap on a distant server using the docker image. 
I configured the ports to listen on other ports than 80->83, 443->446 and 22 (because I already have an other application on those ports).
the docker run command works well and I get the front page on example.com:83/

Great ! But when I click on the login link which is the url "http://example.com:83/account/login.php" I got a 302 Http code that redirect my browser on : "https://**localhost**/account/login.php"

However, I can reach the page when I manually ask for "https://example.com:446/account/login.php"

So the question is : is there a piece of configuration where I can set the hostname or is that a bug ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the configuration file `/etc/tuleap/conf/local.inc` to tell Tuleap where it's running.

Specifically you need to update the 2 following values:

- `sys_default_domain`
- `sys_https_host`